# How to use Wi-Fi through a login page?

Tags: wireless, 13.04

I have a ThinkPad with Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail). I found that whenever I try to connect to Wi-Fi in Starbucks (where a login page is needed), it never succeeds. The same thing happens when I try to log into Wi-Fi in college where login is also needed. The login page does not appear as it used to on Windows.

What is the problem and what information should I provide?

Comment: Do other wifis work? Do other wifis with a login page work? It may be a wrong config of starbucks redirect.

Comment: How did these pages appear on Windows, and what appears instead in Ubuntu? What browser or browsers have you tried on Ubuntu, and what browser/s did you us on Windows? Please edit your question to add this information. If you're a student, professor, or other member of the campus community, then you should be able to consult with the college's IT department about the problem; perhaps they can provide some insight. I recommend adding whatever ideas they have to your question (or posting them as an answer if they fix the problem). You may not get similar support at a cafe, but you can try.

Answer (score 2):

Wireless networks like that are called Captive Portals. [Wikipedia's Captive Portal article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal#Implementation) has notes on how the common implementations work.

One reason they might fail is if you have specified a static IP address, or have specified a DNS server, in your interface configuration. A lot of these captive portals rely on you using *only* the settings (IP/netmask/gateway/DNS) provided by their DHCP server.

I've known folks who prefer to use OpenDNS or Google Public DNS rather than their ISP or LAN's DNS servers, and aren't able to use captive portals which rely on DNS spoofing using their own private DNS servers.