# Connect to free Wi-Fi network - how to log into network (Captive portal)?

Tags: wireless

Each time when I connect to free Wi-Fi (caffe, bus, Wi-Fi provided by the city) using Android smartphone, I see a popup message which redirects me to log in webpage.
After acceptance of network conditions, I am able to surf over the Internet.

However, when I try to connect to such Wi-Fi from my laptop (Linux Mint), message is not displayed and I'm constantly disconnected. 
I don't know which page I should open to log into/accept conditions. How can I log into such network (I assume it's needed?). Is such information provided in any logs? Why it is not working "out-of-the-box"?

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339244/how-to-use-wi-fi-through-a-login-page) seems to be similar question, but I still don't know how to open login page.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly this problem, and I found the solution [here](https://blog.ham1.co.uk/2016/02/06/cannot-sign-in-using-hotel-wifi-on-linux-ubuntu-mint/).

Specifically, as directed, here's what I did:

1. Comment out `dns=dnsmasq` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` (i.e. put a # at the beginning of the line)
2. Restart network-manager: `sudo service networking restart`

For me, worked like a charm. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.